# Error installing Flink in DCOS

Tags: digital-ocean, apache-flink, dcos

I've deployed DCOS on DigitalOcean with the following configuration

```
digitalocean_token = "***"

region = "fra1"

master_size = "4GB"

agent_size = "4GB"

boot_size = "4GB"

dcos_cluster_name = "digitalocean-dcos"

dcos_master_count = "1"

dcos_agent_count = "4"

dcos_public_agent_count = "1"

dcos_installer_url = "https://downloads.dcos.io/dcos/stable/dcos_generate_config.sh"

dcos_ssh_key_path = "./do-key"

dcos_ssh_public_key_path = "./do-key.pub"

ssh_key_fingerprint = "***"
```

Installing Flink fails both through the GUI and through the DCOS CLI.

Apparently the error is this:

```
2017-07-29 17:10:05,553 ERROR org.apache.flink.mesos.runtime.clusterframework.MesosApplicationMasterRunner  - Mesos JobManager initialization failed
java.net.UnknownHostException: digitalocean-dcos-agent-00: digitalocean-dcos-agent-00: Name or service not known
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1505)
```

Copied from here:
flink--mesos-appmaster-digitalocean-dcos-agent-00.log

```
2017-07-29 17:10:04,930 WARN  org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader                       - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2017-07-29 17:10:05,223 INFO  org.apache.flink.mesos.runtime.clusterframework.MesosApplicationMasterRunner  - --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-07-29 17:10:05,224 INFO  org.apache.flink.mesos.runtime.clusterframework.MesosApplicationMasterRunner  -  Starting Mesos AppMaster (Version: 1.3.1, Rev:1ca6e5b, Date:20.06.2017 @ 10:08:43 PDT)
2017-07-29 17:10:05,224 INFO  org.apache.flink.mesos.runtime.clusterframework.MesosApplicationMasterRunner  -  Current user: root
2017-07-29 17:10:05,224 INFO  org.apache.flink.mesos.runtime.clusterframework.MesosApplicationMasterRunner  -  JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM - Oracle Corporation - 1.8/25.111-b14
2017-07-29 17:10:05,224 INFO  org.apache.flink.mesos.runtime.clusterframework.MesosApplicationMasterRunner  -  Maximum heap size: 880 MiBytes
2017-07-29 17:10:05,224 INFO  org.apache.flink.mesos.runtime.clusterframework.MesosApplicationMasterRunner  -  JAVA_HOME: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
2017-07-29 17:10:05,229 INFO  org.apache.flink.mesos.runtime.clusterframework.MesosApplicationMasterRunner  -  Hadoop version: 2.3.0
2017-07-29 17:10:05,229 INFO  org.apache.flink.mesos.runtime.clusterframework.MesosApplicationMasterRunner  -  JVM Options:
2017-07-29 17:10:05,229 INFO  org.apache.flink.mesos.runtime.clusterframework.MesosApplicationMasterRunner  -     -Dlog.file=/mnt/mesos/sandbox/flink--mesos-appmaster-digitalocean-dcos-agent-00.log
2017-07-29 17:10:05,230 INFO  org.apache.flink.mesos.runtime.clusterframework.MesosApplicationMasterRunner  -     -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/flink-1.3.1/conf/log4j.properties
2017-07-29 17:10:05,230 INFO  org.apache.flink.mesos.runtime.clusterframework.MesosApplicationMasterRunner  -     -Dlogback.configurationFile=file:/flink-1.3.1/conf/logback.xml
2017-07-29 17:10:05,230 INFO  org.apache.flink.mesos.runtime.clusterframework.MesosApplicationMasterRunner  -  Program Arguments:
2017-07-29 17:10:05,230 INFO  org.apache.flink.mesos.runtime.clusterframework.MesosApplicationMasterRunner  -     -Dblob.server.port=20262
2017-07-29 17:10:05,230 INFO  org.apache.flink.mesos.runtime.clusterframework.MesosApplicationMasterRunner  -     -Djobmanager.heap.mb=256
2017-07-29 17:10:05,230 INFO  org.apache.flink.mesos.runtime.clusterframework.MesosApplicationMasterRunner  -     -Djobmanager.rpc.port=20261
2017-07-29 17:10:05,230 INFO  org.apache.flink.mesos.runtime.clusterframework.MesosApplicationMasterRunner  -     -Djobmanager.web.port=20260
2017-07-29 17:10:05,230 INFO  org.apache.flink.mesos.runtime.clusterframework.MesosApplicationMasterRunner  -     -Dmesos.artifact-server.port=20263
2017-07-29 17:10:05,230 INFO  org.apache.flink.mesos.runtime.clusterframework.MesosApplicationMasterRunner  -     -Dmesos.initial-tasks=1
2017-07-29 17:10:05,231 INFO  org.apache.flink.mesos.runtime.clusterframework.MesosApplicationMasterRunner  -     -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.cpus=1
2017-07-29 17:10:05,231 INFO  org.apache.flink.mesos.runtime.clusterframework.MesosApplicationMasterRunner  -     -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.mem=1024
2017-07-29 17:10:05,231 INFO  org.apache.flink.mesos.runtime.clusterframework.MesosApplicationMasterRunner  -     -Dtaskmanager.heap.mb=512
2017-07-29 17:10:05,231 INFO  org.apache.flink.mesos.runtime.clusterframework.MesosApplicationMasterRunner  -     -Dtaskmanager.memory.preallocate=true
2017-07-29 17:10:05,231 INFO  org.apache.flink.mesos.runtime.clusterframework.MesosApplicationMasterRunner  -     -Dtaskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots=1
2017-07-29 17:10:05,231 INFO  org.apache.flink.mesos.runtime.clusterframework.MesosApplicationMasterRunner  -     -Dparallelism.default=1
2017-07-29 17:10:05,231 INFO  org.apache.flink.mesos.runtime.clusterframework.MesosApplicationMasterRunner  -     -Dmesos.resourcemanager.framework.role=*
2017-07-29 17:10:05,231 INFO  org.apache.flink.mesos.runtime.clusterframework.MesosApplicationMasterRunner  -     -Dsecurity.kerberos.login.use-ticket-cache=true
2017-07-29 17:10:05,231 INFO  org.apache.flink.mesos.runtime.clusterframework.MesosApplicationMasterRunner  -  Classpath: /flink-1.3.1/lib/flink-python_2.10-1.3.1.jar:/flink-1.3.1/lib/flink-shaded-hadoop2-uber-1.3.1.jar:/flink-1.3.1/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/flink-1.3.1/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar:/flink-1.3.1/lib/flink-dist_2.10-1.3.1.jar::/etc/hadoop/conf/:
2017-07-29 17:10:05,231 INFO  org.apache.flink.mesos.runtime.clusterframework.MesosApplicationMasterRunner  - --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-07-29 17:10:05,234 INFO  org.apache.flink.mesos.runtime.clusterframework.MesosApplicationMasterRunner  - Registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2017-07-29 17:10:05,252 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: mesos.master, zk://leader.mesos:2181/mesos
2017-07-29 17:10:05,252 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: mesos.failover-timeout, 60
2017-07-29 17:10:05,254 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: mesos.initial-tasks, 1
2017-07-29 17:10:05,254 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: mesos.resourcemanager.tasks.container.type, mesos
2017-07-29 17:10:05,254 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: mesos.resourcemanager.tasks.container.image.name, openjdk:8-jre
2017-07-29 17:10:05,255 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: mesos.resourcemanager.tasks.cpus, 1
2017-07-29 17:10:05,255 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: mesos.resourcemanager.tasks.mem, 1024
2017-07-29 17:10:05,257 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.rpc.port, 6123
2017-07-29 17:10:05,258 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.heap.mb, 256
2017-07-29 17:10:05,258 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.heap.mb, 512
2017-07-29 17:10:05,258 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots, 1
2017-07-29 17:10:05,258 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.memory.preallocate, false
2017-07-29 17:10:05,258 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: parallelism.default, 1
2017-07-29 17:10:05,259 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.web.port, 8081
2017-07-29 17:10:05,306 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: mesos.master, zk://leader.mesos:2181/mesos
2017-07-29 17:10:05,307 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: mesos.failover-timeout, 60
2017-07-29 17:10:05,307 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: mesos.initial-tasks, 1
2017-07-29 17:10:05,307 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: mesos.resourcemanager.tasks.container.type, mesos
2017-07-29 17:10:05,307 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: mesos.resourcemanager.tasks.container.image.name, openjdk:8-jre
2017-07-29 17:10:05,307 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: mesos.resourcemanager.tasks.cpus, 1
2017-07-29 17:10:05,308 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: mesos.resourcemanager.tasks.mem, 1024
2017-07-29 17:10:05,308 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.rpc.port, 6123
2017-07-29 17:10:05,308 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.heap.mb, 256
2017-07-29 17:10:05,308 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.heap.mb, 512
2017-07-29 17:10:05,308 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots, 1
2017-07-29 17:10:05,308 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.memory.preallocate, false
2017-07-29 17:10:05,308 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: parallelism.default, 1
2017-07-29 17:10:05,309 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.web.port, 8081
2017-07-29 17:10:05,402 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.security.modules.HadoopModule        - Hadoop user set to root (auth:SIMPLE)
2017-07-29 17:10:05,553 ERROR org.apache.flink.mesos.runtime.clusterframework.MesosApplicationMasterRunner  - Mesos JobManager initialization failed
java.net.UnknownHostException: digitalocean-dcos-agent-00: digitalocean-dcos-agent-00: Name or service not known
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1505)
    at org.apache.flink.mesos.runtime.clusterframework.MesosApplicationMasterRunner.runPrivileged(MesosApplicationMasterRunner.java:216)
    at org.apache.flink.mesos.runtime.clusterframework.MesosApplicationMasterRunner$1.call(MesosApplicationMasterRunner.java:181)
    at org.apache.flink.mesos.runtime.clusterframework.MesosApplicationMasterRunner$1.call(MesosApplicationMasterRunner.java:178)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext$1.run(HadoopSecurityContext.java:43)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:40)
    at org.apache.flink.mesos.runtime.clusterframework.MesosApplicationMasterRunner.run(MesosApplicationMasterRunner.java:178)
    at org.apache.flink.mesos.runtime.clusterframework.MesosApplicationMasterRunner.main(MesosApplicationMasterRunner.java:139)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: digitalocean-dcos-agent-00: Name or service not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1500)
    ... 10 more
```

Log (this is looping infinitely)

```
+ '[' '' '!=' '' ']'
+ add_mesos_configurations
++ hostname -f
hostname: Name or service not known
+ add_if_non_empty jobmanager.rpc.address
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ add_if_non_empty mesos.resourcemanager.framework.role '*'
+ '[' -n '*' ']'
+ export 'FLINK_JAVA_OPTS= -Dblob.server.port=20262 -Djobmanager.heap.mb=256 -Djobmanager.rpc.port=20261 -Djobmanager.web.port=20260 -Dmesos.artifact-server.port=20263 -Dmesos.initial-tasks=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.cpus=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.mem=1024 -Dtaskmanager.heap.mb=512 -Dtaskmanager.memory.preallocate=true -Dtaskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots=1 -Dparallelism.default=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.framework.role=*'
+ FLINK_JAVA_OPTS=' -Dblob.server.port=20262 -Djobmanager.heap.mb=256 -Djobmanager.rpc.port=20261 -Djobmanager.web.port=20260 -Dmesos.artifact-server.port=20263 -Dmesos.initial-tasks=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.cpus=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.mem=1024 -Dtaskmanager.heap.mb=512 -Dtaskmanager.memory.preallocate=true -Dtaskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots=1 -Dparallelism.default=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.framework.role=*'
+ add_if_non_empty mesos.resourcemanager.framework.principal ''
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ add_if_non_empty mesos.resourcemanager.framework.secret ''
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ add_ssl_configurations
+ [[ '' == true ]]
+ add_kerberos_configurations
+ add_if_non_empty security.kerberos.login.use-ticket-cache true
+ '[' -n true ']'
+ export 'FLINK_JAVA_OPTS= -Dblob.server.port=20262 -Djobmanager.heap.mb=256 -Djobmanager.rpc.port=20261 -Djobmanager.web.port=20260 -Dmesos.artifact-server.port=20263 -Dmesos.initial-tasks=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.cpus=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.mem=1024 -Dtaskmanager.heap.mb=512 -Dtaskmanager.memory.preallocate=true -Dtaskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots=1 -Dparallelism.default=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.framework.role=* -Dsecurity.kerberos.login.use-ticket-cache=true'
+ FLINK_JAVA_OPTS=' -Dblob.server.port=20262 -Djobmanager.heap.mb=256 -Djobmanager.rpc.port=20261 -Djobmanager.web.port=20260 -Dmesos.artifact-server.port=20263 -Dmesos.initial-tasks=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.cpus=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.mem=1024 -Dtaskmanager.heap.mb=512 -Dtaskmanager.memory.preallocate=true -Dtaskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots=1 -Dparallelism.default=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.framework.role=* -Dsecurity.kerberos.login.use-ticket-cache=true'
+ '[' '' '!=' '' ']'
+ add_if_non_empty security.kerberos.login.principal ''
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ [[ '' != '' ]]
+ update_log_level
+ [[ INFO != '' ]]
+ sed -ie 's/log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file/log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file/g' /flink-1.3.1/conf/log4j.properties
+ exec /flink-1.3.1/bin/mesos-appmaster.sh -Dblob.server.port=20262 -Djobmanager.heap.mb=256 -Djobmanager.rpc.port=20261 -Djobmanager.web.port=20260 -Dmesos.artifact-server.port=20263 -Dmesos.initial-tasks=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.cpus=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.mem=1024 -Dtaskmanager.heap.mb=512 -Dtaskmanager.memory.preallocate=true -Dtaskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots=1 -Dparallelism.default=1 '-Dmesos.resourcemanager.framework.role=*' -Dsecurity.kerberos.login.use-ticket-cache=true
+ FLINK_SECURITY_DIR=/etc/security/flink
+ mkdir -p /etc/security/flink
+ export APPLICATION_WEB_PROXY_BASE=/service/flink
+ APPLICATION_WEB_PROXY_BASE=/service/flink
+ add_flink_configurations
+ export FLINK_JAVA_OPTS=
+ FLINK_JAVA_OPTS=
+ export 'FLINK_JAVA_OPTS= -Dblob.server.port=20262'
+ FLINK_JAVA_OPTS=' -Dblob.server.port=20262'
+ export 'FLINK_JAVA_OPTS= -Dblob.server.port=20262 -Djobmanager.heap.mb=256'
+ FLINK_JAVA_OPTS=' -Dblob.server.port=20262 -Djobmanager.heap.mb=256'
+ export 'FLINK_JAVA_OPTS= -Dblob.server.port=20262 -Djobmanager.heap.mb=256 -Djobmanager.rpc.port=20261'
+ FLINK_JAVA_OPTS=' -Dblob.server.port=20262 -Djobmanager.heap.mb=256 -Djobmanager.rpc.port=20261'
+ export 'FLINK_JAVA_OPTS= -Dblob.server.port=20262 -Djobmanager.heap.mb=256 -Djobmanager.rpc.port=20261 -Djobmanager.web.port=20260'
+ FLINK_JAVA_OPTS=' -Dblob.server.port=20262 -Djobmanager.heap.mb=256 -Djobmanager.rpc.port=20261 -Djobmanager.web.port=20260'
+ export 'FLINK_JAVA_OPTS= -Dblob.server.port=20262 -Djobmanager.heap.mb=256 -Djobmanager.rpc.port=20261 -Djobmanager.web.port=20260 -Dmesos.artifact-server.port=20263'
+ FLINK_JAVA_OPTS=' -Dblob.server.port=20262 -Djobmanager.heap.mb=256 -Djobmanager.rpc.port=20261 -Djobmanager.web.port=20260 -Dmesos.artifact-server.port=20263'
+ export 'FLINK_JAVA_OPTS= -Dblob.server.port=20262 -Djobmanager.heap.mb=256 -Djobmanager.rpc.port=20261 -Djobmanager.web.port=20260 -Dmesos.artifact-server.port=20263 -Dmesos.initial-tasks=1'
+ FLINK_JAVA_OPTS=' -Dblob.server.port=20262 -Djobmanager.heap.mb=256 -Djobmanager.rpc.port=20261 -Djobmanager.web.port=20260 -Dmesos.artifact-server.port=20263 -Dmesos.initial-tasks=1'
+ export 'FLINK_JAVA_OPTS= -Dblob.server.port=20262 -Djobmanager.heap.mb=256 -Djobmanager.rpc.port=20261 -Djobmanager.web.port=20260 -Dmesos.artifact-server.port=20263 -Dmesos.initial-tasks=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.cpus=1'
+ FLINK_JAVA_OPTS=' -Dblob.server.port=20262 -Djobmanager.heap.mb=256 -Djobmanager.rpc.port=20261 -Djobmanager.web.port=20260 -Dmesos.artifact-server.port=20263 -Dmesos.initial-tasks=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.cpus=1'
+ export 'FLINK_JAVA_OPTS= -Dblob.server.port=20262 -Djobmanager.heap.mb=256 -Djobmanager.rpc.port=20261 -Djobmanager.web.port=20260 -Dmesos.artifact-server.port=20263 -Dmesos.initial-tasks=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.cpus=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.mem=1024'
+ FLINK_JAVA_OPTS=' -Dblob.server.port=20262 -Djobmanager.heap.mb=256 -Djobmanager.rpc.port=20261 -Djobmanager.web.port=20260 -Dmesos.artifact-server.port=20263 -Dmesos.initial-tasks=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.cpus=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.mem=1024'
+ export 'FLINK_JAVA_OPTS= -Dblob.server.port=20262 -Djobmanager.heap.mb=256 -Djobmanager.rpc.port=20261 -Djobmanager.web.port=20260 -Dmesos.artifact-server.port=20263 -Dmesos.initial-tasks=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.cpus=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.mem=1024 -Dtaskmanager.heap.mb=512'
+ FLINK_JAVA_OPTS=' -Dblob.server.port=20262 -Djobmanager.heap.mb=256 -Djobmanager.rpc.port=20261 -Djobmanager.web.port=20260 -Dmesos.artifact-server.port=20263 -Dmesos.initial-tasks=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.cpus=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.mem=1024 -Dtaskmanager.heap.mb=512'
+ export 'FLINK_JAVA_OPTS= -Dblob.server.port=20262 -Djobmanager.heap.mb=256 -Djobmanager.rpc.port=20261 -Djobmanager.web.port=20260 -Dmesos.artifact-server.port=20263 -Dmesos.initial-tasks=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.cpus=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.mem=1024 -Dtaskmanager.heap.mb=512 -Dtaskmanager.memory.preallocate=true'
+ FLINK_JAVA_OPTS=' -Dblob.server.port=20262 -Djobmanager.heap.mb=256 -Djobmanager.rpc.port=20261 -Djobmanager.web.port=20260 -Dmesos.artifact-server.port=20263 -Dmesos.initial-tasks=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.cpus=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.mem=1024 -Dtaskmanager.heap.mb=512 -Dtaskmanager.memory.preallocate=true'
+ export 'FLINK_JAVA_OPTS= -Dblob.server.port=20262 -Djobmanager.heap.mb=256 -Djobmanager.rpc.port=20261 -Djobmanager.web.port=20260 -Dmesos.artifact-server.port=20263 -Dmesos.initial-tasks=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.cpus=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.mem=1024 -Dtaskmanager.heap.mb=512 -Dtaskmanager.memory.preallocate=true -Dtaskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots=1'
+ FLINK_JAVA_OPTS=' -Dblob.server.port=20262 -Djobmanager.heap.mb=256 -Djobmanager.rpc.port=20261 -Djobmanager.web.port=20260 -Dmesos.artifact-server.port=20263 -Dmesos.initial-tasks=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.cpus=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.mem=1024 -Dtaskmanager.heap.mb=512 -Dtaskmanager.memory.preallocate=true -Dtaskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots=1'
+ export 'FLINK_JAVA_OPTS= -Dblob.server.port=20262 -Djobmanager.heap.mb=256 -Djobmanager.rpc.port=20261 -Djobmanager.web.port=20260 -Dmesos.artifact-server.port=20263 -Dmesos.initial-tasks=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.cpus=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.mem=1024 -Dtaskmanager.heap.mb=512 -Dtaskmanager.memory.preallocate=true -Dtaskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots=1 -Dparallelism.default=1'
+ FLINK_JAVA_OPTS=' -Dblob.server.port=20262 -Djobmanager.heap.mb=256 -Djobmanager.rpc.port=20261 -Djobmanager.web.port=20260 -Dmesos.artifact-server.port=20263 -Dmesos.initial-tasks=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.cpus=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.mem=1024 -Dtaskmanager.heap.mb=512 -Dtaskmanager.memory.preallocate=true -Dtaskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots=1 -Dparallelism.default=1'
+ '[' '' '!=' '' ']'
+ add_mesos_configurations
++ hostname -f
hostname: Name or service not known
+ add_if_non_empty jobmanager.rpc.address
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ add_if_non_empty mesos.resourcemanager.framework.role '*'
+ '[' -n '*' ']'
+ export 'FLINK_JAVA_OPTS= -Dblob.server.port=20262 -Djobmanager.heap.mb=256 -Djobmanager.rpc.port=20261 -Djobmanager.web.port=20260 -Dmesos.artifact-server.port=20263 -Dmesos.initial-tasks=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.cpus=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.mem=1024 -Dtaskmanager.heap.mb=512 -Dtaskmanager.memory.preallocate=true -Dtaskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots=1 -Dparallelism.default=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.framework.role=*'
+ FLINK_JAVA_OPTS=' -Dblob.server.port=20262 -Djobmanager.heap.mb=256 -Djobmanager.rpc.port=20261 -Djobmanager.web.port=20260 -Dmesos.artifact-server.port=20263 -Dmesos.initial-tasks=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.cpus=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.mem=1024 -Dtaskmanager.heap.mb=512 -Dtaskmanager.memory.preallocate=true -Dtaskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots=1 -Dparallelism.default=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.framework.role=*'
+ add_if_non_empty mesos.resourcemanager.framework.principal ''
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ add_if_non_empty mesos.resourcemanager.framework.secret ''
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ add_ssl_configurations
+ [[ '' == true ]]
+ add_kerberos_configurations
+ add_if_non_empty security.kerberos.login.use-ticket-cache true
+ '[' -n true ']'
+ export 'FLINK_JAVA_OPTS= -Dblob.server.port=20262 -Djobmanager.heap.mb=256 -Djobmanager.rpc.port=20261 -Djobmanager.web.port=20260 -Dmesos.artifact-server.port=20263 -Dmesos.initial-tasks=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.cpus=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.mem=1024 -Dtaskmanager.heap.mb=512 -Dtaskmanager.memory.preallocate=true -Dtaskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots=1 -Dparallelism.default=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.framework.role=* -Dsecurity.kerberos.login.use-ticket-cache=true'
+ FLINK_JAVA_OPTS=' -Dblob.server.port=20262 -Djobmanager.heap.mb=256 -Djobmanager.rpc.port=20261 -Djobmanager.web.port=20260 -Dmesos.artifact-server.port=20263 -Dmesos.initial-tasks=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.cpus=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.mem=1024 -Dtaskmanager.heap.mb=512 -Dtaskmanager.memory.preallocate=true -Dtaskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots=1 -Dparallelism.default=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.framework.role=* -Dsecurity.kerberos.login.use-ticket-cache=true'
+ '[' '' '!=' '' ']'
+ add_if_non_empty security.kerberos.login.principal ''
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ [[ '' != '' ]]
+ update_log_level
+ [[ INFO != '' ]]
+ sed -ie 's/log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file/log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file/g' /flink-1.3.1/conf/log4j.properties
+ exec /flink-1.3.1/bin/mesos-appmaster.sh -Dblob.server.port=20262 -Djobmanager.heap.mb=256 -Djobmanager.rpc.port=20261 -Djobmanager.web.port=20260 -Dmesos.artifact-server.port=20263 -Dmesos.initial-tasks=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.cpus=1 -Dmesos.resourcemanager.tasks.mem=1024 -Dtaskmanager.heap.mb=512 -Dtaskmanager.memory.preallocate=true -Dtaskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots=1 -Dparallelism.default=1 '-Dmesos.resourcemanager.framework.role=*' -Dsecurity.kerberos.login.use-ticket-cache=true
```

I get a continuously running "Deploying 1 of 1" with status Unhealthy.

On the other hand, installing other packages like Kafka and Redis succeeds.

Comment: what package version are you trying to run?

Comment: Use the latest one here works for me http://universe.dcos.io/#/package/flink/version/latest

Comment: @QasimSarfraz thx. I'll try it and tell you the outcome.

Comment: @QasimSarfraz not working for me. Have you deployed DCOS on DigitalOcean? I used latest. 1.3.1-1.2-1.2. Actually I tried every package versions and they all get stuck. Deployment of Flink runs forever...

Comment: I am using the standard installation guide and it works for me. I had a dns issue initially as in the Job Manager and Task Manager nodes weren't able to resolve each hostname but once I had it fixed it works for me. Let me go through the digital ocean guide to see if there is any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was working off an on-premises installation and got similar errors. Turns out CentOS 7 doesn't add its hostname to the /etc/hosts file during installation. I simply had to add the line

```
127.0.0.1 myhostname
```

Or add your hostname to that line if it already exists

Started working straight away

Comment: This worked for me as well.  I deployed a DC/OS cluster v1.11 using CoreOS as my image and attempting to run Flink v1.4.2.  CoreOS also didn't have the hostname mapped in the `/etc/hosts` file.  Why the mapping is needed is that the flink docker container attempts to execute `hostname -f` [here](https://github.com/mesosphere/dcos-flink-service/blob/1.4.2/container/appmaster/runit/service/flink/run#L37) which is used to setup some configuration.

Comment: Taking this problem one step further, I think there is a bug with DC/OS because the hostname assignment comes from DC/OS right?  So DC/OS should be sticking in the mapping into `/etc/hosts` during installation at the same time assigning the host name.

Comment: Or perhaps the bug is with the flink project where it shouldn't be doing `hostname -f` inside the docker container.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is explained [here](https://github.com/dcos/examples/tree/master/flink/1.9) under **Troubleshooting** for AWS. Although can be adapted to DigitalOcean.

Citing from the link above:

> There is a situation which can occur where the JobMaster is not able
>   to resolve its hostname. This causes the TaskManager container that
>   launches to never communicate with the JobManager and the cluster
>   never enters the ready state. In the logs will contain something
>   similar to
>
> ```
> 2017-07-29 17:10:05,553 ERROR org.apache.flink.mesos.runtime.clusterframework.MesosApplicationMasterRunner - Mesos JobManager initialization failed
> java.net.UnknownHostException: agentname: agentname: Name or service not known
> at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1505)
> ```
>
> This can be resolved by [enabling "DNS Hostname" support in the
>   VPC](https://www.ericmichaelstone.com/?p=7430) for the agents.
>
> ```
> aws ec2 modify-vpc-attribute --vpc-id vpc-a01106c2 --enable-dns-hostnames "{\"Value\":true}"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to a bug in the dcos-flink package that was fixed a few days ago.

[fix: Set jobmanger.rpc.address to current host](https://github.com/mesosphere/dcos-flink-service/commit/dcc837fa61aaa43740155e42695560941bfc0b26)

Assumedly the fix hasn't been deployed to your DCOS universe yet.